# Filter Array If Date >= Today()

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use the filter function to show only data in combination with the importrange function that meets certain conditions. I currently have the following formula:

```
=filter(ImportRange("XXXXXXX","Sheet1!A2:A"),ISBLANK(ImportRange("XXXXXXX","Sheet1!C2:C")),CONDITION2?)
```

So I currently have 1 condition that works, import the range if the value in range(C2:C) is blank; however, I am having trouble figuring out adding the second condition where it will import the range if there is a date and if that date is `>= Today()` in range(C2:C).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is preferable to you use [Query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) instead:

```
=QUERY(ImportRange("XXXXXXX","Sheet1!A2:C"),"Select Col1 where Col1 is not NULL and Col3 is NULL or Col3 > now()")
```

In order for this solution to work, column C must contain the dates in the correct format or null values (empty cells).

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you sir, this works! I was actually using this formula before after googling but for some reason when I use the select A where C it doesn't work. but it works when i change it to Col1 and Col3

Comment: @Marios You could improve your formula by using `"Select Col1 where Col1 is NOT null and Col3 is null or Col3 > now()"` instead

Comment: @user14397867  *"...when I use the select A where C it doesn't work. but it works when i change it to Col1 and Col3 "*. That is because you now use the `ImportRange ` function.